# Get IP Address for a specific network interface on Ruby

Tags: ruby, linux

I need to get the IP address for each of my network interfaces. The issue is that the standard ruby method `Socket.ip_address_list` only returns to me the adress list, but no information about which interface corresponds to the IP address.

```
#<Addrinfo: 127.0.0.1>
#<Addrinfo: 192.168.13.175>
#<Addrinfo: 172.17.0.1>
#<Addrinfo: ::1>
#<Addrinfo: fe80::4685:ff:fe0d:c406%wlan0>
```

I am basically looking for the equivalent of NodeJS `os.networkInterfaces()[interfaceName]`.

How can I know the IP address for a specific network interface?

Comment: try this http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/ethernet/0.1.3/Ethernet/Devices

Answer (score 6):

**Please let me know if there's a way to get this information using Ruby 1.9.X**

I updated Ruby to 2.3 version and then used `Socket.getifaddrs` (available since Ruby 2.1).

```
require 'socket'
addr_infos = Socket.getifaddrs
addr_infos.each do |addr_info|
    if addr_info.addr
        puts "#{addr_info.name} has address #{addr_info.addr.ip_address}" if addr_info.addr.ipv4?
    end
end
```

Output:

```
$ ruby2.3 getInterfaces.rb 
lo has address 127.0.0.1
wlan0 has address 192.168.13.175
docker0 has address 172.17.0.1
```

Comment: If you're still using Ruby 1.9 you're living on borrowed time, it's no longer receiving updates. Usually upgrading from 1.9 to 2.x is relatively painless, but you'll have to try and see how much friction you get.

Answer (score 0):

#### One-liner

```rb
require 'socket'; Socket.getifaddrs.map(&:addr).select(&:ipv4?).map(&:ip_address).select { |x| x !~ /\A127/ }
```

Comment: Shorter isn't necessarily better.